# Is it possible to assert who is the parent/child by looking at DNA sequence only?

Tags: genetics

Suppose I have whole genome sequences for two people of the same sex. I know one person is the parent of the other, but I do not know who is the parent and who is the child. Is it possible to determine with certainty the direction of descent using the sequencing information alone? Assume that the individuals were sampled at the same age so that you can't tell parentage from telomeres or other age-related markers.

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking if DNA testing can identify parentage? (I think you know the answer to that) And isn't this assuming that the genetic material somehow survived for longer than the Carbon 14 did?

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't think it is the same, no. I don't care to look if they are relative here, I care to know which one engendered the other, only by looking at their genes. And yes, it is by assuming I have the full knowledge of both genetic codes. I picked 100 k years as an example to remove C14 possibility out of the question, but if you prefer, make it, say, 5000 years ago or even a decade ago (but then please don't cheat using C14 :) ).

Comment: What do you mean by 'only looking at the chromosomes'? Staring at them down a microscope? Sequencing them?

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform I've edited your question for clarity and to incorporate the information from the comments. Feel free to roll back my edits if you feel they change the spirit of your question.

Comment: Take a chromosome of individual A. For each gene check if an identical copy is found in individual B. If it is the case then B is the parent of A.

Comment: @rerus if the gene is identical in both, why does that rule out A being the parent of B?

Comment: @swbarnes2 B is the parent iff for one of two chromosomes 1 of individual A, all the genes alleles are found in B. This is a naive model due to intragenic crossover, mutations, and mitosis crossover, so you'll need to compute a B->A inheritance score for each chromosome of A.

Comment: My main source is https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21438/ "Mitotic crossing-over is rare" as it is the main thing that can mess entirely what I'm saying.

Comment: If one chromosome is identical between A and B, how can that possibly distinguish anything at all between them?  If two students in a class turn in identical papers, how is that evidence that A must have copied from B, and that B could not have copied from A?

Comment: @swbarnes2 ... meiotic crossover 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/pmc/articles/PMC4353236/ https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/pmc/articles/PMC3478297/

Comment: @reuns I had to read your comment twice to realize what you mean and that you are right and swbarnes2 just didn't understand you. It would recommend you to turn your comment into answer with diagram. The point is that _one_ chromosome in A is identical to parts of _two_ chromosomes in B. This is not a symmetrical pattern. Another way to look at it is that out of 4 homologous chromosomes involved 3 have at least some part not identical to anything. Problem with this approach is that with current methods we can't get full chromosome haplotypes.

Answer (score 3):

If A is XY and B is XX, if A is the parent, A should pass on their X chromosome intact to the offspring.  If B is the parent, than the X chromosome A receives would have undergone crossing over with B's other X chromosome before being passed to A.

Otherwise, I don't think you could do it from sequence alone.

I guess if the circumstances were right, you could include haplotpye information, and you could tell; if one person had top to bottom haplotypes only found in China, and the other was half Chinese haplotypes and half African haplotypes, the simplest explanation is that the person with one ethnic origin is the parent, and the person with two is the offspring